# Can't see logs in Azure Log Stream

Tags: azure

In my Web Api App, I have the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("in get...");
        return "value";
    }
}
```

I want to be able to see the log "in get..." on Azure when I publish it. On Azure, in the `App Service Logs` I turn on `Application Logging (Filesystem)` and set the level to `Information`. In the `Log Stream`, when I go to the url of the method, I see in the logs:

> Connecting... 2020-02-09T06:07:38  Welcome, you are now connected to
>   log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the
>   timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
>   2020-02-09 06:08:07.158 +00:00 [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting
>   HTTP/1.1 GET
>   http://testapi20200208104448.azurewebsites.net/api/values/5 2020-02-09
>   06:08:07.159 +00:00 [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing
>   action method TestApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (TestApi) with
>   arguments (5) - ModelState is Valid 2020-02-09 06:08:07.160 +00:00
>   [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor:
>   Executing ObjectResult, writing value
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.

But I don't see my log "in get..."

Comment: .net or .netcore app?, hosted in linux or windows?

Comment: .netcore hosted in windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39611) for .NET core (but for .NET framework, it can work well).

As a workaround for .NET core web application, I suggest you can use `ILogger`, which can write message to Application Logs.
In `Startup.cs` -> `Configure` method, re-write Configure method like below:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   //your other code

   //add the following 2 lines of code.
   loggerFactory.AddConsole();
   loggerFactory.AddDebug();

   app.UseStaticFiles();

   //your other code
}
```

then in `ValuesController`:

```cs
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
   private readonly ILogger _logger; 

   public ValuesController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
      _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ValuesController>();
   }

   // GET api/values
   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<string> Get()
   {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
   }

   // GET api/values/5
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public string Get(int id)
   {
      //System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("in get...");

      //use ILogger here.
      _logger.LogInformation("in get...");
      return "value";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer did not fully work for me on aspnetcore 3.1, but it led me to this article, which gave me all information I needed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1