# Application logs are not showing up in log stream for .NET core app running in Azure app service (AAS) windows

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET core app running in Azure App service windows instance. I have enabled the logs for my application in "App service Logs" configuration with the log level as Verbose. But the application logs are not showing up in the log stream nor in the /LogFiles/Application folder in Azure app. However, when I deploy the same application to App service in Linux, I can see the logs under LogFiles folder.

I am not sure why the logs for the same application/code work differently in AAS on windows vs Linux. Am I missing any configuration?

I also tried installing "ASP.NET Core Logging Integration" extension on AAS running on windows, I could see other MS logs but not the application logs. Again, this is only happening on AAS Windows.

**Update:**
It seems like a known issue for .NET core 3.1. I came across the following links that is recommending to use ILogger;

1. [Can't see logs in Azure Log Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133976/cant-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream)
2. [I cannot see logs in Azure Log Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749481/i-cannot-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could make sure you have set the right log level.

If you set the log level to error, it will just log the error inside that folder. I suggest you could try to modify it and try again.

Log setting:

[image]

Log result:

[image]

Comment: Log level was already to verbose but still no application logs were seen in Log stream. I updated my original question.